# SQLite Update Query add 1 to value

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am struggling with using the update function of Sqlite in my android app. I am simply trying to add 1 to the value that already exists in a row.

This is what I currently have:

```
 public void updateItemQty(int SKU) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String p[] = new String[]{String.valueOf(SKU)};
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(Keys.Key_SENTQTY, Keys.Key_SENTQTY + 1);
        try {
            db.update(Keys.Key_CARTONITEMTABLE, args, Keys.Key_SKU + " = ? AND " + Keys.Key_STATUS + " = 0 ", p);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        db.close();
    }
```

This issue being that instead of adding 1 to my key.KEY_SENTQTY, it just enters sent_qty1 into the table! How do I achieve what I am after?

Thanks

Comment: db.rawQuery with standard UPDATE code for such cases(`update table set col1 = col1 + 1 where col2=somevalue`) or read value first add 1 in java code and then update with new value using db.update (for safe you should use transaction) ... there is no way to increment/add value directly using db.update

Comment: @selvin, whack this an answer and I will mark it correct

Comment: nah, i'm too lazy, you can always answer itself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research and be pointed in the right direction by @Selvin, this is not possible as ContentValues are set pre-query, so you don't have the value of a row to add too.

My Assumption was that this was executed when the query was run, which was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

technically, you could set `sent_qty` to `sent_qty + 1`, but not using contentValues, as these are escaped thoroughly.

Using `execSQL`, you can do:

```
db.execSQL("update " + Keys.Key_CARTONITEMTABLE 
         + " set " + Keys.Key_SENTQTY + " = " + Keys.Key_SENTQTY + " + 1 where " 
         + Keys.Key_SKU + " = " + SKU + " and " + Keys.Key_STATUS + " = 0");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Keys.KEY_SENTQTY` is a `String`. How are you supposed to add an `int` to a `String`?

Comment: Badly explained but kind of right, the reason being that ContentValues are set pre-query, so there is no value to Keys.KEY_SENTQTY